# C# - HttpClient redirects url to login therefore the POST is sent to a false URL

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

I'm currently using **linqToTwitter** to authenticate my winforms application with twitter, this is needed to receive the needed informations I will need later on to send a username change request.

After the user authenticated himself he should enter a desired username and the application would check if the username is aviable. This works great so far.

**My problem:**

The API doesnt offer the feature to update usernames so I've started to try my luck using the `HttpClient` which seems to send the request succesfully. But the `HttpClient` doesn't seem to be authenticated with twitter. Even thought I'
ve used the `authenticity_token` created by the desktop application through the oauth request.

While logging the request using fiddler I've realized that update profile URL is redirecting me back to the login site. Which means that my data isn't ending up where I want it to end.

[Screenshot of the Fiddler response uploaded using Gyazo..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnyFu.png)

I've been trying around more such things as sending the `HttpClient` first to the authentication site of twitter which ive found in an application on [github](https://github.com/kronoscloud/Twitter-Handler-Turbo/blob/master/Twitter%20Turbo/Twitter.cs) which is sadly not working.

Does anyone have a idea, what I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any kind of suggestions / help.

**Some other informations:**

I know the twitter API allows to change some `update_profile` variables but it's not offering to change the username.

**Code which should handle the username change:**

```
public async Task ChangeHandle(string Handle)
{
    using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = Cookies, UseCookies = true, AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate })
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage() { Method = HttpMethod.Post, RequestUri = ChangeHandleUri, Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(changehandle_request) })
    {
        try
        {
            string userAuthPassword = bunifuMetroTextbox2.Text;

            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("_method", "PUT"));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("authenticity_token", userInformations[1]));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("orig_uname", userInformations[2]));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("orig_email", userData[1]));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[screen_name]", Handle));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[email]", userData[1]));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[lang]", userData[2]));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[time_zone]", userData[3]));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[country]", userData[2]));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[requires_login_verification]", "1"));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login_verification_enabled", "false"));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[no_username_only_password_reset]", "1"));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[autoplay_disabled]", "1"));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user[personalize_timeline]", "1"));
            changehandle_request.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("auth_password", userAuthPassword));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "twitter.com";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = new Uri("https://twitter.com/settings/account");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (responseString.Contains("Thanks, your settings have been saved."))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Handle Changed Successfully", "Response");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Handle could not be changed", "Error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a 200 status code? Check that it isn't 302?

Comment: 302 status on the update profile url and a 200 status on the redirected url, which should mean the request/post i'm sending to the url isn't authenticated. Therefore I'm being redirected to the 302 login site.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons why your code won't work:

1. You haven't included an Authentication header with the proper OAuth string. You can visit the [Twitter API OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth) page for more information on how to implement this.
2. You're trying to update parameters that the Twitter API doesn't make available. You can visit the [Twitter API update_profile](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile) endpoint definition page to see which parameters are available.

You mentioned that you were using LINQ to Twitter. This might be easier:

```
        var user = await twitterCtx.UpdateAccountProfileAsync(
            name: "Joe Mayo",
            url: "https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter",
            location: "Las Vegas, NV",
            description: "Testing the Account Profile Update with LINQ to Twitter.",
            includeEntities: true,
            skipStatus: true);
```

You can see an entire demo for this code at the [LINQ to Twitter Console Samples page for AccountDemo.cs](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/blob/master/Samples/net46/CSharp/ConsoleSamples/AccountDemos.cs).

Comment: I know the twitter API itself isn't offering to upate the @username. But you can do it through the browser, so I thought it could be done this way also using a HttpClient

Comment: @steckden That's a display name.

Comment: Yes the following code you posted would update the display name. But I'm trying to change the username stored in: https://twitter.com/username and this can't be done through the API but it can be done through the web-browser here: https://twitter.com/settings/account So i thought i would create a HttpClient to do this. But the request I post is being redirected to this site: https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=%2Fsettings%2Faccounts%2Fupdate because I'm not authenticated.

Comment: Is there a way, to use the oauth token generated by linqtotwitter with a HttpClient without being redirected back to the login?

Comment: @steckden I don't know if it's possible to do what you're doing. Even if you did figure it out, the solution would be brittle and subject to unpredictable change because it isn't part of the standard API.